# Visual Studio 2015 suddenly don't want to create new variables in classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm struggling with the issue almost whole day, I didn't find any answer in the internet. I know this fix is just to shift one small thing, however I have not idea which one. Uninstall (using TotalUninstaller) of visual studio (community 2015) didn't fix mine problem. That's it for the word of introduction ...

I can't define any object/variable in classes. Does not matter is it in new project or existing.

Example Snippet of a class in existing project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AGDS
{
    public class Similarity
    {
        public string index;
        public double distance;
        public double similarityRate;
        public Similarity(string index, double distance)
        {
            this.index = index;
            this.distance = distance;
        }
        // NEW PART WHICH HAS BEEN ADDED
        int b;
        b = 100;
        // END
    }
}
```

When I try to build I receive following errors

```
Error   CS1519  Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration AGDS
Error   CS0103  The name 'b' does not exist in the current context. AGDS
```

Moreover in any project in Program.cs class I'm able to define.
I have strange felling that installation of local SQL server could broke something ... 
Has anyone got idea what can be wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: `b = 100;` needs to be in a function.

Comment: I don't believe I'm so stupid :) I had a break from C# where I was coding mainly in web languages and bash and I completely forgot paradigms of C# ...

    public void setB()
    {
        this.b = 43;
    }

works ...

Comment: I think creating a set function to assign a member value is probably an overkill.

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible to declare variables **then** assign values to those variables outside of a function?

Try to do this:

```
public class Similarity
{
    public string index;
    public double distance;
    public double similarityRate;
    public Similarity(string index, double distance)
    {
        this.index = index;
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    int b = 100;  //new code
}
```

Comment: no it is not... however you can create fields and assign them values just like you did...

Answer (score 1):

You are able to set a default value for the `b` member like this: `int b = 100;`.  However, after the member declaration, you won't be able to assign a value to `b` member outside a function.  When you want to assign a value to a member, you should determine when it should be done.  So if you want to set the `b` value when a instance of `Similarity` is created, you can assign it in the class constructor:

```
int b;
public string index;
public double distance;
public double similarityRate;
public Similarity(string index, double distance)
{
    this.index = index;
    this.distance = distance;
    b = 100;
}
```

On a side note, if you want to declare `b` as a public property, the right way to do this would be `public int b {get; set;}`.  Since C# 6, you can also set a default value directly to the a property: `public int b {get; set;} = 100;`

Answer (score 0):

```
Error   CS1519  Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration AGDS
Error   CS0103  The name 'b' does not exist in the current context. AGDS
```

These two messages are a bit vague, but they are correct.  In the code example, it is attempting to act like code within a method or function.  Put that same code into a method or function and it will work.

If you intended b to be a field or property... You can shrink the declaration and assignment to one line. For a property use Getters and Settters.